# Patching a single class in Glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws

We're experiencing a bug in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (specifically, in the WSEndpointImpl class in Metro module) which is fixed but due in Glassfish 4.0 or some next release in the 3.1 branch hopefully. As this fix is critical for our application, we would like to patch this class alone and install it somehow to Glassfish, before waiting for the next release. Is this possible? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish supports swapping in other versions of certain modules via the [Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/gchif.html) and according to the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) JAX-WS is among the replaceable components.

You just have to copy the updated version into the `/lib/endorsed` directory of your domain, but I'm pretty sure you can also put your file in the `/lib/endorsed` directory of the Glassfish server itself.

See a practical example [in this blog entry](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bhaktimehta/archive/2007/01/developing_webs.html)